# (Python) Discord bot disconnect from a voice chat

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to know how to make a discord bot disconnect from a voice channel. Currently this is the code i have to join a voice channel

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def joinvoice(ctx):
    #"""Joins your voice channel"""
    author = ctx.message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
    await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)
```

I need the code to disconnect from a voice channel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py disconnect from voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906874/discord-py-disconnect-from-voice-channel)

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs The question you are linking is a duplicate, not vice versa

Comment: @DanielW. While it's true that the one I linked came after this one, I believe it has a much simpler solution, which is why I linked it as a duplicate. `ctx.guild.voice_client` can be used instead of iterating through all servers,.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need the voice client object which is returned from `await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)`. This object has a method `disconnect()` which allows you to do just that. The client also has an attribute `voice_clients` which returns an iterable of all the connected voice clients as can be seen [at the docs](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.voice_clients). With that in mind, we can add a command called leavevoice (or whatever you want to call it).

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def joinvoice(ctx):
    #"""Joins your voice channel"""
    author = ctx.message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def leavevoice(ctx):
    for x in client.voice_clients:
        if(x.server == ctx.message.server):
            return await x.disconnect()

    return await client.say("I am not connected to any voice channel on this server!")
```

Here in the `leavevoice` command, we looped over all the voice clients the bot is connected to in order to find the voice channel for that server. Once found, disconnects. If none, then the bot isn't connected to a voice channel in that server.

Comment: When i use your code to join it works, then when i type s.leavevoice it outputs. (I am not connected to any voice channel on this server!) even though it is in my voice channel