# Discord.py how to leave channel without ctx

Tags: python, discord

This is a discord bot function that is supposed to join a voice channel when someone joins, play a song for 5 seconds and then leave the channel.

The problem is that with a @bot.event I cant pass context to it, so I found a way to connect with the after arg but I cant find a way to leave the channel.

```
 @bot.event                                                                                                                                                                                           
     async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):                                                                                                                                              
         if not before.channel and after.channel:                                                                                                                                                         
             await after.channel.connect()                                                                                                                                                                
             voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients)                                                                                                                                                 
             voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))                                                                                                                                               
             time.sleep(5)                                                                                                                                                                                
             await after.channel.disconnect()
```

Its says

```
AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'disconnect
```

I know that the way I do this function is probably wrong so if you guys know the "proper" way I hope you will notice me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Python) Discord bot disconnect from a voice chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612538/python-discord-bot-disconnect-from-a-voice-chat) - i.e. `VoiceChannel.connect()` returns a `VoiceClient`, it is _that_ that you disconnect from, not the channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this way to leave the voice channel without passing context:

```
 @bot.event                                                                                                                                                                                           
 async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):                                                                                                                                              
     if not before.channel and after.channel:                                                                                                                                                         
         await after.channel.connect()                                                                                                                                                                
         voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients)                                                                                                                                                 
         voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))                                                                                                                                               
         time.sleep(5)                                                                                                                                                                                
         await voice.disconnect()
```