# Discord.py bot won't leave a voice chat

Tags: python, discord, bots

i'm currently using these commands to make my bot leave/join a vc. Joining works fine, but leaving won't work.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.command()
  async def join(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel!")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
      await ctx.voice_channel.move_to(voice_channel)

  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

Any help in understanding why would be really appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Python) Discord bot disconnect from a voice chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44612538/python-discord-bot-disconnect-from-a-voice-chat)

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(self,arg):
    await arg.voice_client.disconnect(force=True)
```

and also replace channel name from ctx to arg cause it takes ctx as current channel (its not possible to type in voice channel afaik)